# svn revision number confusion

Tags: svn, kde-4

when i add a new file or folder to my repository svn revises it after the latest revision number available in the repo, i.e. does not revise it as 1.
is it the way svn works? also, i am using *kdesvn* as the svn client; could it be the client's fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how revisions work. Once a commit is processed the revision number assigned is next number after the last latest revision number. You're tracking the revisions of the repository as a whole, not of the particular file.